# How to create an array of Object of some type?

Tags: java

What's syntax for creating an array of Objects of some class type?

`Object<SomeClassType<T>>[] array`?

Comment: Object[] perhaps? Object is "the parent class". I don't understand what are you exactly trying to do.

Comment: Generic array creation is not allowed. Rather than a `List<String>[]` you should use a `List<List<String>>` or a `String[][]`.

Comment: `java.lang.Object` does not take any type parameters. Do you mean some other kind of `Object` type here?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an array of a generic type is not allowed, but what you can do, is creating one with wildcard and casting it. The cast will give you a warning, but as the array only contains nulls by default, it can be done safely.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Object<SomeClassType<T>>[] array = (Object<SomeClassType<T>>[]) new Object<?>[length]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this would allow you to create an array.

```
String[] testArray = new String[3];
testArray[0] = "one";
testArray[1] = "two";
testArray[2] = "three";

String[] testArray = {"one","two","three"};
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of ways to declare an array of objects of some class type. For example,

```
1. MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[# of elements];
```

Then initialize each as, myArray[0] = new MyClass();, myArray[1] = new MyClass(), etc..
     or via a for-loop

```
2. MyClass[] myArray = {new MyClass(), new MyClass(), ...};
```